# Owl Carousel 2 Random?

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/randomOrder.html

How can I do the same thing with owl carousel 2 ? http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/

Now did the upgrade and can not figure out how to do random,and this old carousel stopped working :(

Please help, how to implement the same in the new Functionality owl carousel 2.

Thank you!

Comment: Please be sure to read the descriptions of the tags you put on your questions. This is not a question about the Web Ontology Language ([tag:owl]), but about the OWL Carousel ([tag:owl-carousel]).

Comment: Does not anyone know how to do this? :(